# Printing Excel files to PDF stops after first file USING Python, win32com

Tags: python, excel, pywin32, win32com, export-to-pdf

**Hey Guys! hope you're having an awesome day, please help :)**

I need to print a specific sheet to PDF out of every Excel file in a dir of thousands.

I keep getting the same error, the first file prints perfectly but when the script advance to the second file I get this error msg:

**File "<COMObject >", line 5, in ExportAsFixedFormat*
*com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147018887), None)**

- The excel version is 2010
- I have already printed and checked the list, it seems legit

here is the code I use:

```
import win32com.client
import os

sheet_list = []
    for file in os.listdir('C:/Users/Guy/Documents/P'):
        if file.endswith('.xlsm'):
        sheet_list.append(file)
 path = ('C:/Users/Guy/Documents/P/')
 file_list = [path + x for x in sheet_list]

def SheetPrint(wb_path):


    o = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

    o.Visible = False

    wb = o.Workbooks.Open(wb_path)
 
    ws_index_list = [2] #say you want to print these sheets
    num = 1
    pdf_path =  ('C:/Users/Guy/Documents/P/pdf/'+str(num))

    print_area = 'A1:G50'

    
    wb.WorkSheets(ws_index_list).Select()

    wb.ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(0, pdf_path )
    wb.WorkSheets(1).Select()
    wb.Close(True)
    num = (num + 1)

    
for i in file_list:
  SheetPrint(i)
```

the code was inspired by this post:
[Print chosen worksheets in excel files to pdf in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16683376/print-chosen-worksheets-in-excel-files-to-pdf-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [win32 ExportAsFixedFormat Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48874767/win32-exportasfixedformat-error)

Comment: this seems like a good lead but the link for the download is broken, and I can't seem to find another one

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20140213052435/http://search.microsoft.com/en-in/DownloadResults.aspx?FORM=DLC&ftapplicableproducts=%5e%22Office%22&sortby=+weight

Comment: I have installed it and it still not working,
Also, the first file does print fine so I don't think its a problem with its ability to print.
I will try to download a newer version of excel, maybe it will help